# Change color of label if mouse not on button

Tags: javafx

JavaFX
So I have code where if mouse on button when color of label is changing

```
AeroportT1.hoverProperty().addListener((event)->tAeroportT1.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0909")));
```

But I need change color back when mouse not on button.

Comment: Consider using CSS for this.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ChangeListener` but not `InvalidationListener` for your purpose

```
AeroportT1.hoverProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
         AeroportT1.setTextFill(newValue ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE));
```

Or you can use `Bindings`

```
AeroportT1.textFillProperty().bind(Bindings.when(AeroportT1.hoverProperty()).then(Color.RED).otherwise(Color.BLUE));
```